# MD5 with more than one parameter

Tags: python, md5

I have to create a password that is a combination of three parameters in MD5:

```
value1 + value2 + value3
```

How to do it in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, basically you can concatenate the three strings as a single string and use the combined string as the input for the md5 function

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> value1 = "value1"
>>> value2 = "value2"
>>> value3 = "value3"
>>> hashlib.md5(value1 + value2 + value3).hexdigest()
'ceba206ca4802a60ca07a411905111b8'
```